# Python log to file user defined function not working

Tags: python

I have the following code with a function to write into a log file, for some reason it doesn't work :-|

```
#!/usr/nin/env python

log_buffer = ""

def print_log(msg):
  global log_buffer
  log_buffer += msg + "\n"
  return
  with open("logging.log","at") as log:
    log.write(msg+"\n")

print_log("Test")
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: why you return before writing to file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea what am I missing here?

your return statement makes the `print_log()` function leave **before** you ever write to the file

but instead of reinventing the wheel, you should instead use the `logging` module!

look at a [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) and implement it, so that way you'll be compatible with libraries you may include in your project, or keep a standard way to use logs if your project is a library. And it provides ways to filter logs to different destinations and so many more powerful features!

Comment: yeah, seems my return was the problem and the write never happened.

Comment: thanks for the tip with logging module and tutorial, I will follow it!